# Combine columns in dojox.grid.DataGrid?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I have a DataGrid that has a data store of the typeL dojox.data.XmlStore. How do I access other xml values for the current node in the function defined in the formatter attribute?
I've looked at formatterScope and that seems to be the right direction, but the documentation is very vague. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the store's reference as the value of `formatterScope`, then in the `formatter` function, you can use `this.getValue()` to get values you need.

However I don't think this is a good design. Formatting of a cell should only depends on the data of the cell only. If you need more information to do the formatting, maybe you should re-consider the design of your data store.

Comment: I was able to combine two cells by using the get attribute.